# ¿Cómo usar ChartJS 4 en modo local?

Tags: chart.js

Necesito usar ChartJS 4 en modo local, sin cargar el .js de CDN para ejecutarlo en un PC sin acceso a internet, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Podes descargar el paquete y hacer la llamada a los scripts de JS de manera local

Comment: si estas usando node, tiene un modulo npm para descargarlo desde el backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descarga chartJS desde los [assets de la release en GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v4.1.1/chart.js-4.1.1.tgz), tendrás un archivo tgz el cual deberás descomprimir y buscar dentro, la carpeta dist hay podrás encontrar la versión de desarrollo de chartJS.

Otra forma es descargar el archivo directamente desde la CDN, es decir busca la CDN por ejemplo https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.1/chart.min.js y guardás el código.